How to deal with partial derivatives when plugging in the Boltzmann equation into the liouville equation?
When plugging in $$f(\vec{r},\vec{v},t) = n(\vec{r},t) \left[\frac{m}{2\pi k_b T(\vec{r},t)}\right]^{3/2} \exp\left[\frac{-m(\vec{v}-\vec{u}(\vec{r},t))^2}{2k_bT(\vec{r},t)}\right]$$
into the Liouville equation, I am confused why we get non zero contributions from the $\partial_t$ and $\nabla_\vec{r}$ terms. Let's take the $\partial_t$ term as an example, why is the term equal to
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial n}\frac{\partial n}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial T}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \vec{u}}\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t} \not=0$$
This is done in Tong's notes on kinetic theory page 45. Shouldn't the partial derivative with respect to time be zero as the distribution function doesn't depend on time explicitly? it only depends on time implicitly through $n,T,\vec{u}$ .  Since we are not taking the total derivative, this doesn't make sense to me.

I suspect the answer is one of ambiguous notation. Consider the difference between $f(\vec{r},\vec{v},t)$ and $f(\vec{r},\vec{v},T,n)$. In the first, we are thinking of $f$ as explicitly a function of $t$, and we have just notationally written $f$ in terms of functions of $t$ for convenience/compactness of notation; think of $T$ and $n$ as explicit expressions that involve $t$ rather than functions of $t$. In the second ($f(\vec{r},\vec{v},T,n)$), we are thinking of $f$ as a function of $T$ and $n$, and so the dependence on $t$ is explicitly implicit.

The answer is what March said.
What Tong is doing is using an Ansatz stating that the time (and spatial) dependence can be fully incorporated in the macroscopic fields. Or said differently:
$$f(r, p, t)\equiv f[n(r, t), u(r,t), T(r,t)|p]$$
Where the bracket denote a "functional dependence". This approximation is called the Chapman-Enskog procedure. In this sense, the partial derivative on $t$ should be understood as the finite difference:
\begin{split}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}&=\dfrac{f(r,p,t+\delta t)-f(r,p,t)}{\delta t}\\&=\dfrac{f[n(r, t+\delta t), u(r,t+ \delta t), T(r,t+\delta t)|p]-f[n(r, t), u(r,t), T(r,t)|p]}{\delta t}
\end{split}
And if you expand this, you see that it corresponds to what you would call a total time derivative of $f$.

So I understand what March said but I think you are pointing out a subtlety that I want to appreciate. How is incorporating the time and spacial dependence into macroscopic fields equivalent to the Chapman-Enskog expansion? My understanding of the expansion is that we expand the distribution function and the space and time derivatives in powers of the Knudsen number.

@realanswers I would say that the Knudsen number is the physically relevant scale above which you expect the theory to hold. But the real deal with the Chapman-Enskog theory is not only an expansion in term of some quantity. The important thing is that the expansion is in the gradient of some macroscopic field. Of course a first order expansion in gradient corresponds to a first order expansion in Knudsen number. But it just sets a scale or serves as a bookeeping parameter.

Most "modern" approaches just use a dummy variable. And then expand the probability distribution in power of this dummy variable. But it is only use to keep track of the order of the gradients at which you perform the expansion. Indeed this formal parameter is related to the Knusden number to set the scale at whixh the theory fails. I like this ref https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.03429&ved=2ahUKEwiEm_bWys-IAxWdVKQEHa_tAwgQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2ODfZagFKC_KOlC6VyQwSF which concerns a granular gas but section 3 might interest you.

A very very nice reference (much easier to follow) is the book by Kirkpatrick Contemporary Kinetic Theory of Matter. By the way, Tong is also doing the Chapman-Enskog expansion, just without a bookeepking term or without any explicit small parameter

I think that a simple expansion in Knudsen number directly on the Boltzmann equation without assuming any separation of time scale (as we do when we use macroscopic field and their gradient) is called a Hilbert expansion. But don't quote me on that. We sometimes also see written or quoted that the Chapman-Enskog expansion belongs to the class of multiple scale perturbation method but it's a bit too much to say that in my opinion..
